# Python + Cronjob: Why doesn’t cronjob execute os.system()?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, cron, scheduling

On Linux Ubuntu, I have a python script which runs fine locally and on time, every 5 minutes, for cronjob:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python /matt/python_scripts/test_script.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But when the python script runs for the cronjob on time, it does not execute the `os.system()` line and skips it inside the python script. Locally, it executes the `os.system()` lines fine.

Why does it do so and how can I get it to execute the `os.system()` code?

Thank you in advance and will be sure to upvote/accept answer

Comment: The question is what is your `os.system` command doing?

Comment: Most likely the command called by `os.system` is not in default path.

Comment: @Coldspeed either `mkdir` or simply executing another script, which all executes perfectly fine when  done locally.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **full** path to the binary you execute (like `/bin/mkdir` or similar).

Comment: Sorry but do you mean do that in `os.system(/bin/mkdir)` like so?

Comment: More like `os.system('/bin/mkdir parameters')` (check if your mkdir is indeed in /bin, /usr/bin or whatever).